# Flag first unique category within group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Question

**Dataset**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a','x'],['a','x'],['a','y'],['a','y'],['b','y'],['b','z'],['c','z']], columns = ['cat1', 'cat2'])

  cat1 cat2
0    a    x
1    a    x
2    a    y
3    a    y
4    b    y
5    b    z
6    c    z
```

I tried many things online but nothing seems to work can anybody please help!!

**Output required: **

```
  cat1  cat2  flag
0    a    x    1
1    a    x    0
2    a    y    1
3    a    y    0
4    b    y    0
5    b    z    1
6    c    z    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html), invert the boolean (`~`) and convert to integer:

```
df['flag'] = (~df['cat2'].duplicated()).astype(int)
```

Or with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df['cat2'].duplicated(), 0, 1)
```

Output:

```
  cat1 cat2  flag
0    a    x     1
1    a    x     0
2    a    y     1
3    a    y     0
4    b    y     0
5    b    z     1
6    c    z     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df.duplicated(['cat2']), 0, 1)
print (df)
  cat1 cat2  flag
0    a    x     1
1    a    x     0
2    a    y     1
3    a    y     0
4    b    y     0
5    b    z     1
6    c    z     0
```

If need first value per group by `cat1` ouput is different:

```
df['flag'] = np.where(df.duplicated(['cat1','cat2']), 0, 1)
print (df)
  cat1 cat2  flag
0    a    x     1
1    a    x     0
2    a    y     1
3    a    y     0
4    b    y     1
5    b    z     1
6    c    z     1
```

EDIT: With your data:

```
#if necessary first sorted value per claim and Date
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.sort_values(['claim','Date'])

df['flag'] = np.where(df.duplicated(['claim']), 0, 1)
print (df)
  claim       Date  flag
0     a 2001-05-01     1
1     a 2002-08-01     0
2     b 2005-09-08     1
3     b 2009-09-08     0
4     b 2020-10-01     0
```

If need first minimal datetime per groups use:

```
print (df)
  claim        Date
0     a  05/01/2001
1     a  08/01/2002
2     b  09/08/2005
3     b  10/01/2020
4     b  09/04/2000
5     b  09/04/2000

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['flag'] = np.where(df.index.isin(df.groupby('claim')['Date'].idxmin()), 1, 0)
```

Or:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['flag'] = np.where(df['Date'].isin(df.groupby('claim')['Date'].transform('min')) &
                      ~df.duplicated(['claim','Date']), 1, 0)
print (df)
  claim       Date  flag
0     a 2001-05-01     1
1     a 2002-08-01     0
2     b 2005-09-08     0
3     b 2020-10-01     0
4     b 2000-09-04     1
5     b 2000-09-04     0
```

Comment: Basically What i want is :  cat1 cat2  flag
    claim        Date         flag
0    a        05/01/2001     1
1    a        08/01/2002     0
2    b        09/08/2005     1
3    b        09/08/2009     0
4    b        10/01/2020     0       First date ( ascending ) for a claim should be flagged as 1

Comment: @RaghavJain - there is some problem with solution? I try your data and working well. Added to answer.